# Commutative diagrams in Opposite Category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I am working on the kernels and co-kernels of morphisms in categories with zero objects. I came across the following: $(C,j:B\to C)$ is a cokernel of $f\in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ $\iff$ $(C,j^{op}:C\to B)$ is a kernel of $f^{op}\in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(B,A)$.

Here, the category $\mathcal{C}$ has a zero object and kernel of any morphism $f:A\to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as the the pair $(Z,i:Z\to A)$ (for $Z\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ and morphism $i\in \text{Hom}(Z,A)$) such that
$f\circ i=0_{ZB}$ where $0_{ZB}:Z\to B$ is the zero morphism.

So, I was wondering if you have a commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ and reversed all the arrows to get a diagram in $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$, then will this diagram also be commutative?

Here are some of my confused thoughts about this. Take $D:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ the functor s.t. $D: A\mapsto A$, $[f:A\to B]\mapsto [f^\text{op}:B\to A]$. This is a contravariant functor becuase the composition $A\to B\to C$ must get mapped to its reverse/dual $C\to B\to A$ in $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$, by definition of composition in opposite categories (very unsure of this statement). So, going back to my problem about kernels, supposing $(Z,i:Z\to A)$ is kernel of $f:A\to B$ i.e. $f\circ i=0_{ZB}$, we get $i^{op}\circ f^{op}=D(i)\circ D(f)=D(f\circ i)=D(0_{ZB})=0_{BZ})$ i.e. $(Z,i^{op}:A\to Z)$ is the co-kernel of $f^{op}:B\to A$.

I think my confusion is about my understanding of opposite categories and their relation to contravariant functors. For instance, should the composition in $D(i)\circ D(f)$ be that of the opposite category? Is it right to say $f^{op}\circ_{op}g^{op}$ is $D(g\circ f)=(g\circ f)^{op}$?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, if you reverse all the arrows of a commutative diagram in $C$, you get a commutative diagram in $C^{op}$. You will confuse yourself tremendously if you name the objects of $C^{op}$ the same as in $C$; I suggest also naming them $A^{op}$ and so forth so you can keep things straight. And yes, the dual of a kernel is a cokernel, and taking opposites reverses the order of composition.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that suggestion (and the statements). I think my confusion about opposite categories was from the fact that my lecture notes used the symbol $f$ for both the morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ and its reverse/dual in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

Comment: Yes, that's also terrible and confusing and your use of $f^{op}$ is much better. It is, in a very meaningful sense, not the same morphism, and same for objects.

Comment: I am new here and hence ignorant about the etiquette of accepting answers, but anyways. I see your comment as answering my questions. So, if you could make your comment an answer I would be glad to accept it.